# How to render all records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, window-functions

I want to display using MYSQL5.5 all records by adding the Count as a new column and using the specific DESC ordering in COUNT.

Sample data:

```
ID|ID_2|FIRST|SECOND|
88|300 |1    |4
81|300 |1    |5
7 |300 |2    |1
33|300 |3    |4
99|300 |1    |4
84|300 |1    |5
6 |300 |1    |4
34|300 |3    |5
```

Query :

```
SELECT a.ID,a.ID_2, a.FIRST, a.SECOND, COUNT(a.ID) as testing
FROM table AS a
WHERE a.ID_2=300
GROUP BY a.ID_2, a.FIRST, a.SECOND
ORDER BY testing DESC
```

With the above code I get the correct COUNT(a.ID) number all the combinations of FIRST & SECOND but also the COUNT.

Results:

```
a.ID|a.ID_2|a.FIRST|a.SECOND|testing|
88  |300   |1      |4       |3        
81  |300   |1      |5       |2
7   |300   |2      |1       |1
33  |300   |3      |4       |1
99  |300   |3      |5       |1
```

But I would like to get the following:

```
a.ID|a.ID_2|a.FIRST|a.SECOND|testing|
88  |300   |1      |4       |3  
99  |300   |1      |4       |3
6   |300   |1      |4       |3      
81  |300   |1      |5       |2
85  |300   |1      |5       |2
7   |300   |2      |1       |1
33  |300   |3      |4       |1
99  |300   |3      |5       |1
```

Could you help with this? Even with a temp table.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is easier to do in MySql 8. So which version of MySql?

Comment: Unfortunately I use MYSQL 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MySQL < 8.0, you can self-join the table with an aggregated subquery that computes the relevant counts :

```
SELECT t.*, t2.testing
FROM
    mytable t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT a.ID_2, a.FIRST, a.SECOND, COUNT(a.ID) as testing
        FROM mytable a
        GROUP BY a.ID_2, a.FIRST, a.SECOND
    ) t2 ON t.ID_2 = t2.ID_2 AND t.FIRST = t2.FIRST AND t.SECOND = t2.SECOND
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response and the valuable help. It was exactly what I needed. Regards, Chris

Comment: Sure! Thanks for your time